# Wrapping component with html element from typescript in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a challenge and can't find any proper solution.
In our system we use a popup, the popup operates when the component is wrapped with a div that has specific css-classes.
I have a base class for all components that want to be a popup. What I want to achieve is that the base component will automatically wrap the child HTML with the needed div (with all css-classes)

Comment: I'd use transclusion and pass child in parent content

Comment: May be content projection or ng-template with *ngTemplateOutlet is helpful to you

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggested help, I followed this explanation here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

and my code now looks like this

```
<app-base-popup [popupId]="getPopupId()" [isLarge]="true">
    <app-iot-device-features-box #iotBoxPopup >
    </app-iot-device-features-box>
</app-base-popup>
```